# How to make scheduled task run program GUI/interactively WITHOUT user logon

Tags: windows, authentication, user-interface, scheduled-tasks

There's a test that needs to be run on Windows interactively.
Now I have a PSSession to create a scheduled task for that.
But I just realized the scheduled task for an interactive run only works when a user logon.
Is it possible to bypass this kind of limitation?

I tried to google whether the scheduled task could run a GUI program without logon, or how to create a logon session programmatically but I failed to get helpful information.
Could anyone help me?